# How to create a standalone command line app with the Symfony2 ClassLoader and Console

Tags: symfony, command-line, autoloader

I am trying to write a command line app using the Symfony2 Console and ClassLoader Components.

This is a screenshot of my code hierarchy and the script being called
[image: code hierarchy]
Here is the CLI script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/code/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php');
    use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

    use BlueHeadStudios\Command\Deployer;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->register();

$input = new ArgvInput();
$debug = $input->hasParameterOption(array('--debug', ''));

$console    = new Application();
$console->add(new Deployer());
$console->run();
```

I get this when running the script

```
dev@server:~/sites/pd/deployer$ php deployer.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in /home/dev/sites/pd/deployer/deployer.php on line 13
```

I know it must be a simple `registerNamespace` call or something similar, but I've tried multiple registrations but cannot get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why run with php, not `app/console`

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/), which will generate `autoload.php` for you to include at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('BlueHeadStudios', __DIR__.'/src/');
$loader->register();

// write your code below
```

Comment: that one line saved my day :)

Comment: UniversalClassLoader is now deprecated. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

You should run the application with `app/console` check the [example here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html)

Comment: The link you are providing says otherwise, the file is named `application.php` so -1, but it is useful to create a standalone application, so +1